# Knockout: Make the whole page wait for result of ajax call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, knockout.js, geolocation

Basically, I would like to call to geoip.com to get the information of the browser user and then use their location to render correctly. But the problem is that using knockout, the page get rendered without waiting for the result of ajax (Even all render code stay behind a success callback). How can I achieve the result?

Changing from ajax to synchronous also does not work.

I am using knockout to bind data to a custom handler in view

```
<div id="main_layout" class=layout data-bind="svg:handle">
....Other HTML....
```

Inside the svg.handle of its viewModel

```
ko.bindingHandlers.svg = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
$.ajax({
        url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'jsonp',     
        success: function(location) {
//        Do everything
}
}
// return viewModel for the HTML
```

Comment: Have a look at `controlsDescendantBindings` (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html). It allows you to prevent knockout from automatically binding the contents of the data-bound element (not the whole page...). If you don't want to do anything before the data has loaded you should load the data from your viewmodel and wait with `ko.applyBindings` until it has loaded.

Comment: You might want to wrap the HTML for the section in an `if` binding controlled by a variable that is false until your ajax call is complete.

Comment: Adding the ajax to viewModels works out for my case. I will do some intensive testing and report back here